# return value than displayed value for a 'display only'page item in oracle apex 5.1

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-apex, oracle12c, oracle-apex-5.1

Can I have a different return value than the displayed value for a  'Display only' page item.

I am using Oracle APEX 5.1 .I have a 'display only' page item whose source is 'sql query' (anything similar is ok) . when query result is null , then I need to display as 'Root' .Now when I use the page item for other computations, I need the null value rather than the display value(which is 'Root'). For all other values(other than null) ,I need to use the exact value.

Can we achieve this in apex?

Answer (score 1):

When using `Display only` type of item, it is expected that you are displaying that items' value (meaning `null` if it's `null` and `Root` if it's `Root`).

What you can do is:

- If `Root` doesn't exist among that column values, you can simply handle in those your latter computation such instances when items' value is `Root` with, for example, `DECODE(:P1_ITEM, 'Root',NULL, :P1_ITEM)`. This is the easiest way if your data allows you, because it involves no additional objects.
- You can create a second item (type `hidden`), so that you have one item to display your values and one item to store your real value. Then you would have to make a `dynamic action` on your stored_value_item to change your display_value_item and refresh it `on change` of stored_value_item
- You can make your item type `Select list`, as it allows your item to have different stored and display value. In that scenario you would have to make item arrow disappear, using custom CSS

Comment: Thank you @Goran. But I got a way to do this much more easier.

Answer (score 0):

this can be achieved using the Based On property of the Display Only item. In this case, set it to Output of PL/SQL Code with the PL/SQL Code being:

```
htp.p(apex_escape.html(coalesce(:item_name), 'Root'));
```